# Perform Segue from ViewController that isn't open

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I have a background task that runs from AppDelegate, when it needs to it displays notifications.

When these notifications are tapped they should direct the user to the ViewController that relates to the notification.

I was wondering if it was possible to perform segues from AppDelagate.

My ViewControllers are in a navigation controller. I'm guessing I have to instantiate my root view controller and perform segue there, just not sure how to do that from appdelegate.

**Edit:**
Here is my code so far, it works it just isn't embedded in my navigation controller

```
 if let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ConversationVC") as? conversationTableViewController {
            if let window = self.window, let rootViewController = window.rootViewController {
                var currentController = rootViewController
                while let presentedController = currentController.presentedViewController {
                    currentController = presentedController
                }
                currentController.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing a code snippet so that we could all see what you are talking about. It will simplify the process for us to help you in your question.

Comment: There is no code snippet to share, not necessary for the question.

Comment: Check this out: https://medium.com/@stasost/ios-how-to-open-deep-links-notifications-and-shortcuts-253fb38e1696

Answer (score 1):

You can't segue from a storyboard that isn't loaded yet.

Depending on your case you could:

1: Send data from the AppDelegate to the initial root view controller of your current storyboard and from there, create multiple segues to the respectable VC depending on the data.

OR

2: Create multiple storyboards (one for each case) and launch the appropriate ones from the AppDelegate according to the notification.

**Edit:** Need to see the storyboard. For the variable, add it to conversationTableViewController and set it up just before you present it:

```
controller.myVar = "someValue"
self.window.rootViewController = controller
self.window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```